# Essential Singularity, proof without Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $f(z)=e^{- \frac{1}{z}}$. I would like to verify that $\forall R > 0, \  f(B(0,R)-\{0\})= \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ without the use of the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.
$B(0,R)=\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < R\}$ would be the open ball or radius $R$ and center $0$.

At first, I thought I may try to prove it by contradiction, therefore I'd suppose that $\exists R > 0$ such that $F(B(0,R)-\{0\}) \not\ni z_0$, where $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. At this point, I thought I could maybe study the singularities of the function $g(z)= \dfrac{1}{f(z)-z_0}$ and possibly deduce some absurdity about the singularities of $f(z)$. Unfortunately, I am unable to conclude.

Would you reason the way I did or is there another method you'd advise me to use?

It also came to my mind that I could try proving it directly by studying the range of $f(z)$, but it looked to me like I had to get too much in detail about the radiuses of the balls, so I gave up.

Comment: This is very easy: pick any non-zero $z_0 \in \mathbb C$.  Determine all the values of $z$ such that $e^{-1/z} = z_0$.  Make sure you find *all* values of $z$, and you will see there is an infinite sequence of them that converges to $0$, so there are plenty within any ball around the origin.

Comment: Note that Casorati-Weierstrass could never tell you what $f(B(0,R)\setminus \{0\})$ is anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, if $g(z)=-1/z$, $R>0$, $U_R=B(0,R)\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}$ and $W_R=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Im}\,z>R\}$, then 
$$
W_{1/R}\subset g[B_R].
$$
Next observe that
$$
\exp[W_r]=\mathbb C\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\},\quad \text{for all $r>0$}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! You've helped me acquire a graphic idea of what's going on.

Comment: Of course you don't get all of $\mathbb C.$

Comment: @zhw. Correct. Zero is excluded!

Answer (score 1):

The function $z\to -1/z$ maps $\{0<|z|<R\}$ onto $\{|z|>1/R\}.$ By $2\pi i$ periocity, $e^z$ maps any open horizontal strip of height greater than $2\pi$ onto the full range of $e^z,$ namely $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$ There are billions of such strips in each $\{|z|>1/R\}.$